# Post request of a form returns empty ImmutableMultiDict to Flask

Tags: javascript, python, forms, post, request

I'm sending a request from a webpage :

```
<script>
  function sendGenre() {
    let form = document.getElementById("genreForm");
    form.value = document.getElementById("genre").value;
    console.log(form.value);
    form.submit();
  }
</script>
```

```
  <form class="adminPlaylistMainForm" action="createlist" id="genreForm" method="POST">
    <div class="playlistGenre">
      <p>From what genre ?</p>
      <select class="adminPlaylistGenreButton" id="genre">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="jazz">Jazz</option>
        <option value="punk">Punk</option>
        <option value="rock">Rock</option>
      </select>
      <p><input type="button" onclick="sendGenre();" value="Send form" /></p>
    </div>
  </form>
```

The back end is:

```
@app.route('/createlist', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def create_list():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("/createlist request.method == POST")
        print(request.form)
    return render_template("tools/createlist.html")
```

The console.log(form.value) in the function prints the value, console.log(form) prints the full `<form>` and its content but in the terminal on the backend side I get:

```
/createlist request.method == POST
ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

Do you have any idea what the problem is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you are submitting the form. You need to add a name attribute to your `select` tag. Like this: `<select class="adminPlaylistGenreButton" id="genre" name="genre">`

If you chose HTML form then you don't need JavaScript. Replace your submit button with `<input type="submit" value="Send form">`